# spring boot : error when add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency

Tags: spring-boot

When I add the simple spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in my pom.xml, i got an error in the pom.xml file.  If I remove that dependency there is no more errors. I am no sure why it is happening, because i am trying to execute a simple jpa example. I haven't had problems if i add others starters dependencies, I only have problems with that specific starter.

I am using Spring STS 3.7.0 to develop my tests.
I use jdk 8.0.0.60

Thank for your help.

my pom.xml (I removed the links in the header because i dont have enought reputatios to post ilimited links)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="(MAVEN LINK)" xmlns:xsi="(W3 LINK)"
    xsi:schemaLocation="LINK">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Exception

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)



    Failure to transfer org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-ext has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from/to spring-ext : The operation was cancelled.

org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from (URL SPRING EDITED) was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-ext has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final from/to spring-ext (URL SPRING EDITED): The operation was cancelled.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependencies[![enter image description here][1]][1]Resolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: did you try to remove dependencies from .m2 repository?(hibernate, jpa) it look like corrupeted download.

Comment: Could you tell me how remove this .m2  dependencies in spring sts ide?. Thank

Comment: Has nothing to do with STS. In your user directory there is a `.m2/repository` directory remove the hibernate stuff from it. Also try running maven from the command line and see if the dependencies are downloaded. My experience with Eclipse and Maven aren't very good (they don't seem to play along nicely).

Comment: :( that don't help me. I continue with the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Maven configurations in your eclipse IDE may be misconfigured when running your Spring Boot application. In order to resolve this problem you need to provide more information on your setup, or you can use Maven from the command line to get more information.

From the terminal, navigate to the directory of your `pom.xml` file. Then run the following command.

```
$ mvn clean install
```

Note the output and if the build is successful you can use the Maven spring-boot plugin to run the application. Use the following maven command:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: When I use only maven it work, I don't understand why it doesn't work with eclipse. I started to use Intellij and I don't have more problems Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

**IntelliJ solution**:

For those facing this issue on IntelliJ, you may just need to reload the project. In your POM.xml file, right-click anywhere and go to Maven->"Reload Project".
[image: Maven->"Reload Project" submenu]

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still facing the issue can do the following :

1. Move to this website visit https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/
2. Download the jar file
3. Import to your ide.
4. Build the project again or at least pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still faces this problem, Hope it solve your problem

I fixed this problem by cleaning Maven(?)

on STS

1. Run - Run As - Maven Clean
2. right click on your project - Maven - Update Project (Alt + F5)
3. select your project with error and check 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases' click Okay and wait

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly same issue and this is how **I solved it**:

**Reason**: It happened because of my IDE. What happen was when maven was downloading its dependencies I exited my IDE and forced closed it (because my IDE was not responding), thus maven downloaded only partial or corrupt Jar dependencies.

**Solution**: In your Personal Computer

Step 1: note down all the problematic class paths, these class paths are provided as error messages in terminal. (Ex: C:\Users\chara.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core **Couldn't find**)

Step2: go to each and every class path and delete the dependencies( note: Dont delete the folder name but delete only files with version in it)

Step3: refresh maven in IDE(for each IDE its a different process; so search how to refresh maven in youtube ). It will freshly download all the dependencies.

Problem Solved